# Problems with installing Ruby on Rails to Synology DSM 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, synology

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails to my Synology NAS server with is running on DSM 5.2. There is installed Ruby 2.2.0. Next I've tried to install Rails. During the installation I was getting these error messages:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150602-13143-1u6fp4x.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    Building has failed. See above output for more information on the failure.
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Can you help me please, anyone?

Thanks, Tomas

Answer (score -1):

You should first install all necessary packages to use nokogiri gem

For Nokogiri

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Then install Nokogiri gem using,

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. Unfortunately, cannot run sudo command on Synology. 
-ash: sudo: not found. Any different idea, please?

Comment: @TomasKocnar You can use `ipkg` command to install package. Please refer this link http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=87922 and let me know